# Sqoop job incremental lastmodified wrong timestamp value

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to create a **Sqoop Job** using **incremental lastmodified**

```
sqoop job --create job_import_test8_by_query_update -- import \
--bindir ./ --connect 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false' \
--username user \
--password pass \
--table test8 -m 2 \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column "timestamp_field" \
--last-value  0 \
--split-by "id" \
--merge-key "id" \
--verbose \
--target-dir /usr/local/sqlImport/1
```

in this example I am having problem with last-value.
Running the first time when last-value is "0" works fine. Then the last value is automatically set to **current_local_time + 4 hours**, so I am losing some records.

It seems that the last-value takes the server timezone value instead of the last record value from the database.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the useTimezone option to your connection string

```
--connect 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC'
```